# Extracting info from a site php not working

Tags: php, regex, extract

```
        <?php
        $url = "http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/20849404";
        $str = file_get_contents($url);
        if (preg_match('/<ul class="personal_ratings"> ([^<]*)<\/ul>/', $str, $matches) > 0) {
            echo $matches[1]; //This is text one
        }

        ?>
```

Hello guys, I'm trying to extract all the personal ratings info from $url I provided, bur for some reason I can't find a way to extract it like this, I've been trying a ton of different ways but I guess it's my lack of regex knowlede working here, it's probably a small dumb mistake but I've been looking to fix this for the last few days now.

Comment: So would using preg_match_all() make any difference?

Comment: If you're inexperienced with regex, there might be other ways to extract info from there..

Comment: It's multiline, so you might need the `m` switch

Comment: where exactly would I put the m?

Answer (score 2):

I see few mistakes:

1. Parts of your expression that you consider as plain text are containing regex special characters. You may consider escaping them or using `preg_quote()` function or using `~` instead of `/` to wrap expression.
2. If `<ul>` node is split to more than one line of html code, you need to add `s` switch.
3. I would personally use `(.*)` with ungreedy switch (`U` at the end of expression)

I don't have time to check this, but this one should work if site structure is same as in your expression: `preg_match('~<ul class="personal_ratings">(.*)</ul>~Us', ...`

Anyway, for parsing HTML it is much easier to use some DOM parser, like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). It is as easy as:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/20849404');
$ratings = $html->find('ul.personal_ratings',0)->innertext;
```

PS. Regex special characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Comment: the modifier you must use is `s`, not `m` (that means line by line in php). `<>:!=` are not special characters, or only in these situations: `(?>...) (?:...) (?=...) (?!...)`. You can write `]` and `}` as literal without escape them.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte : Not really... `$str = '<div>something</div>'; $is = preg_match('/<div>(.*)<\/div>/',$str,$match); echo $is;` the result is 0. `$str = '<div>something</div>'; $is = preg_match('~<div>(.*)</div>~',$str,$match); echo $is;` the result is 1. `$str = '<div>something</div>'; $is = preg_match('/\<div\>(.*)\<\/div\>/',$str,$match); echo $is;` the result is 1.

Comment: And about `m` switch... I always use `s` but when read Marks Baker comment (above) changed that without checking. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I have made a copy paste of the first test and I obtain 1 (not 0). About the m and s modifiers, it is a little confusing since Ruby use m for the dotall mode.

Comment: @FlashThunder You said the first code will return 0, well no. It does return 1 and here's a demo on [100+ php versions](http://3v4l.org/S1OE0). `<>` doesn't need to be escaped especially not in a character class, even a dot `.` doesn't need to be escaped in a character class. `[.]` will match a dot, and not any character. As for the `U` modifier, it seems a preference but it will get complicated when you have several quantifiers. As for `preg_quote()`, you mostly use it when there is input from an untrust worthy source. Finally, use an [online tester](http://regex101.com) to get a visual view.

Comment: My server returns 0. But I have some custom regular expression extensions, so maybe it is because of it. Sorry for messing up then and good to know that it should work. Nice site, though.

Comment: @FlashThunder Sunday/monday morning and your server is drunk. You've got a tough monday :)

Comment: @HamZa Got tough few months, I'm barely alive. And... what am I doing here??? Responding some idiotic (no offence) questions instead of working.

Comment: @FlashThunder hehe, you're addicted ! Anyways feel free to ask for help